# Mounting another VM's .vdi in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, disk

I have two VMs in VirtualBox. For exmaple, VM 1 runs Red Hat, and VM 2 runs Ubuntu. For the Red Hat VM I have redhat.vdi and redhat2.vdi, and for the Ubuntu VM I have ubuntu.vdi and unbuntu2.vdi.

Each VM can access its own virtual disks without problem.

How can I access ubuntu.vdi from the Red Hat virtual machine, using VirtualBox?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is how you add another virtual hard disk to a VM in VirtualBox.

1. Go into the VirtualBox Manager and make sure both VMs are shut down
2. Right-click on the VM in question and pick Settings
3. Go into the Storage category
4. Select the controller on which you want to connect the virtual hard disk
5. Click the "Add attachment" button and select "Add hard disk" from the popup menu
6. Pick "Choose existing disk"
7. Tell VirtualBox which hard disk file you want to add, and click Open

When you start the VM the next time, the disk will be available just as if you had installed a second physical hard disk in a real computer.

Answer (score 3):

For me the accepted answer didn't work. I was getting an error message along the lines of

> Cannot register the hard disk ... {uuid} because a hard disk ‘...’
>   with UUID {uuid} already exists.

I found [using the command line](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?p=33678) to change the UUID allowed me to attach the drive originally used in a different VM

```
VBoxManage internalcommands sethduuid path/to/drive.vdi
```

Answer (score 2):

Remember !

(Add or set VM)Settings -> Storage -> Adds new storage controller -> Add IDE Controller -> Select the newly added IDE Controler -> click Add hard-disk-> Choose existing disk.

Voilà.

[image]